# Как убрать эту обводку в boostrap 5?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap5

Я не понимаю как убрать эту обводку, методы которые уже написаны не работают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите [mcve], демонстрирующий эту обводку

Comment: box-shadow: none;

Comment: Посмотрите в DevTools в разных состояниях, что за это отвечает (правильно выше сказали, `box-shadow` в состоянии `:focus-visible`) и через переменные (не перебивать, опять же выше сказали, но не совсем правильно), уберите тень. Всё в документации расписано по переменным: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/buttons/#variables (в итоге это `--bs-btn-focus-box-shadow`)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar выглядит как ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

box-shadow: none; –
Dias
дал ответ на этот вопрос.